# Lodash 4: How to omit Object properties if they contain a certain part of a string?

Tags: lodash

Is it possible to use Lodash's `omit` method and remove keys that may contain the string `_old` appended to them ?

For example, here is my JSON object:

```
{
  "name": "Canada",
  "shortName": "CanadaEH",
  "shortName_old": "Canada",
  "fullName": "The NEW Republic of Canada",
  "fullName_old": "The Republic of Canada",
  ...etc...
}
```

I have imported the `omit` package in my app like so:

`import { omit } from 'lodash'`

This works when I do this :

```
filteredFields() {
      return omit(this.myObj, ['name'])
    }
```

I get back the object without those omitted properties just as expected.

However, adding it like so does not work:

`return omit(this.myObj, ['name', '_old'])`

How can I also omit the keys that may contain `_old` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_.omitBy()` method accepts a predicate function, which is called with the current value and key of the property. You can then check the key for the existence of the string.

```js
const obj = {
  "name": "Canada",
  "shortName": "CanadaEH",
  "shortName_old": "Canada",
  "fullName": "The NEW Republic of Canada",
  "fullName_old": "The Republic of Canada",
}

const result = _.omitBy(obj, (v, k) => k.endsWith('_old'))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: thx! Posted another question similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69176285/vuejs2-and-lodash4-how-to-nest-v-for-with-another-v-for-in-an-html-table